# WSO2 EI - SalesForce Connector not connecting to partial instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Getting the below errors when I am trying to connect to Salesforce, Anything essential am I missing?

//TID[-1234] [EI] [2019-03-19 20:40:40,174] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} - The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/createSFBuzz URL.

//TID[-1234] [EI] [2019-03-19 20:40:40,174] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:116) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:603) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:85) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:547) org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:120) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70) org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:224) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151) org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My Proxy Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="createSFBuzz"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.accessToken)" name="accessToken"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.apiUrl)" name="apiUrl"/>

         <property expression="json-eval($.clientId)" name="clientId"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.refreshToken)" name="refreshToken"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.clientSecret)" name="clientSecret"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.hostName)" name="hostName"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.apiVersion)" name="apiVersion"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.registryPath)" name="registryPath"/>
         <property expression="json-eval($.intervalTime)" name="intervalTime"/>
         <salesforcerest.init>
            <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
            <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
            <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
            <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
            <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
            <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
            <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
            <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
            <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
         </salesforcerest.init>
         <log level="full" separator=","/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"success":"Connection Successful"}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the salesforce connector, but in the send mediator afterwards. It has no idea where to send anything. You have a send mediator without a defined endpoint, and most likely without a To header that points to a valid endpoint.

What are you trying to achieve with the Send mediator?

Comment: Agree.. Even after removing that, I am unable to connect and retrieve from Salesforce Box.. I have imported the certificates also. Anything very essential am i missing here?

Comment: Currently your flow is not complete either way.  You now never get to your outSequence, maybe move the payload factory and the respond to your inSequence and try again.  See if you still get an error then, and if so what the error is.

Comment: As already mentioned by ophychius you will never get to the outSequence. Difficult to say what the real problem is without more information. What's the output you're getting now? Have you tried to enable debug level for org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire? There you can see what's exchanged between wso2 and salesforce. If I remember right, there's also inside salesforce some page where you can see login information for your client.

Comment: The Actual connection is successful, only was revealed after enabling the Wire logs.